# Ansible: What's wrong with my "with_itmes" in playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I register 3 hosts key and try to loop my host let another remote host save the key

```
- setup:

- name: Generate Public Key On 3nodes
  openssh_keypair:
    path: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    comment: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['new_percona']  

- name: register public key
  shell: cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  register: public_key
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['new_percona']

- name: Add Nodes Public Key On master-0
  lineinfile: 
    dest: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    line: "{{ hostvars['{{ item }}']['public_key']['stdout'] }}"
  with_items:
    - percona-0
    - percona-1
    - percona-2
  when: '"master-0" in inventory_hostname'
```

and the result

```
TASK [Install : Add Nodes Public Key On master-0] ******************************
fatal: [master-0]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: \"hostvars['{{ item }}']\" is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/tmp/awx_5004_1s769t9j/project/roles/Install/tasks/install-percona.yml': line 62, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Add Nodes Public Key On master-0\n  ^ here\n"}
```

I also try

```
- name: Add Nodes Public Key On master-0
  lineinfile: 
    dest: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    line: "{{ hostvars['{{ groups[new_percona] }}']['public_key']['stdout'] }}"
  when: '"master-0" in inventory_hostname'
```

or loop

```
- name: Add Nodes Public Key On master-0
  lineinfile: 
    dest: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    line: "{{ hostvars['{{ item }}']['public_key']['stdout'] }}"
  loop: [ 'percona-0', 'percona-1', 'percona-2' ]
  when: '"master-0" in inventory_hostname'
```

But above are wrong

How to use variable to loop the host?

this is working if just single host

```
- name: Add Nodes Public Key On master-0
  lineinfile: 
    dest: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    line: "{{ hostvars['percona-0']['public_key']['stdout'] }}"
  when: '"master-0" in inventory_hostname'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use curly braces inside curly braces.

```
line: "{{ hostvars[item]['public_key']['stdout'] }}"
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you! It is working for with_items if I give specific host name. 
But I try to put "{{ inventory_hostname in groups['new_percona'] }}" under with_items,
hope the hostname will loop. But failed.

Comment: You're thinking too complex. `with_items: "{{ groups['new_percona'] }}"` gives you the host name as item. Then you can access the host vars of these hosts.

Comment: You are correct! It is working! Thank you very much!